# Unexpected difference between two pieces of sql

Tags: postgresql

I have two pieces of sql which I think should give identical results and do not.  They both involve a function

```
create or replace function viewFromList( lid integer, offs integer, lim integer ) returns setof resultsView as $xxx$
   BEGIN
    return query select resultsView.* from resultsView, list, files
                 where  list_id=lid and
                        resultsView.basename = files.basename and
                        idx(imgCmnt,file_id) > 0
                 order by idx(imgCmnt,file_id)
                 limit lim offset offs ;
     return;
   END;
$xxx$
```

The first is:

```
        drop table if exists t1;
        create temp table t1 as select * from viewFromList( lid, frst, nmbr::integer );
        select count(*) into rv.height from t1;
```

The second is

```
DECLARE
     t1 resultsView;
....
     select viewFromList( lid, frst, nmbr::integer ) into t1;
     select count(*) into rv.height from t1;
```

Seems to me, rv.height should get the same value in both cases.  It doesn't.  If it matters, the correct answer in my case is 7, the second code produces 12.  I have, of course, looked at the result of the call to viewFromList with the appropriate values.  When run in psql, it returns the expected 7 rows.

Can someone tell me what's going on?

Thanks.

Comment: resultsView is a view whose definition involves 4 other tables.  I will insert code for viewFromList; however, I don't see how to set up the state needed to produce a fiddle.

Comment: I am doing the same computation in both cases, the only difference is the 2 lines in the original post.  I was thinking that the difference would be explained by something which I do not understand about SQL, possibly involving the difference between use of a  temp table and a declared local variable.  I understand that the situation is not perfect but it is the best I know how to do.  I certainly appreciate your time and effort, and everyone else's as well.

Comment: To expand on Ryan's point: I don't notice anything wrong with the code as you've presented which would cause a difference. So if you're posting to sanity-check, that's your answer. That might mean you're passing in different values to the function call, it might mean something strange is going on, it might mean many things, and we can't tell which if any of those without more info.